# Evolution of 'deign' and 'disdain'

Tags: etymology

*This question just popped into my head yesterday. I guess it might be too basic (or too impossible) for EL&U; but I thought I'd give it a shot.*

How come these two words managed to evolve to different spellings? Surely in the days when the grammar nazis ruled the earth with their gimlet eyes and blood-red pens, they should have caught this?

From [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=deign):

> deign - c.1300, from O.Fr. *deignier* (Mod.Fr. *daigner*), from L. *dignari* "to deem worthy or fit" (cf. It. *degnare*, Sp. *deñar*), from *dignus* "worthy" (see *dignity*).
>
> disdain (v.) late 14c., from O.Fr. *desdeignier* "disdain, scorn, refuse, repudiate," from *des-* "do the opposite of" (see *dis-*) + *deignier* "treat as worthy" (see *deign*).

Comment: They did, but they did not deign it to be worth the trouble; their disdain was to great.

Comment: @JefSahol: "too"  (You did nazi that coming?)

Comment: I won't dane to reply.

Comment: Perhaps if they'd had blood-red eyes and gimlet pens (like any self-respecting copy editor), they would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of [this blog entry](http://cephalogenic.blogspot.com/2008/03/dig.html) was wondering the very same thing, and came up with this:

> Both words come from Latin "dignari", "to judge worthy". The "-gn" of
>   "deign" comes from Old French "deigner", a close successor to
>   "dignari"; **its disappearance in "disdain" comes from a newer, Middle
>   English version of the word "deinen", and its offshoot, "disdainen"
>   (when spelling was a lot freer than it is now).**